# Java PDF Viewer

Tags: java, pdf, rcp, pdfrenderer

I am using java and RCP and I am trying to show pdf Document with Acrobat on my views. 
I don't need to change them. 
I have this error with this code. Any idea how to resolve this problem?. P.s.: it works good same times.

```
PDFFile pdfFile;
pdfFile = PdfFileLoader.loadPdf(file, new NullProgressMonitor());
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new OneDimensionalPdfDocument(pdfFile, new NullProgressMonitor());
pdfViewer.setPdfDocument(pdfDocument);

Error from PdfDocument pdfDocument = new OneDimensionalPdfDocument(pdfFile, new NullProgressMonitor()) : Unsupport CMap format: 6
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
at java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getShort(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.pdfview.font.ttf.HmtxTable.setData(HmtxTable.java:79)
at com.sun.pdfview.font.ttf.TrueTypeTable.createTable(TrueTypeTable.java:113)
at com.sun.pdfview.font.ttf.TrueTypeFont.getTable(TrueTypeFont.java:106)
at com.sun.pdfview.font.TTFFont.getOutline(TTFFont.java:129)
at com.sun.pdfview.font.TTFFont.getOutline(TTFFont.java:89)
at com.sun.pdfview.font.OutlineFont.getGlyph(OutlineFont.java:118)
at com.sun.pdfview.font.PDFFont.getCachedGlyph(PDFFont.java:307)
at com.sun.pdfview.font.PDFFontEncoding.getGlyphFromEncoding(PDFFontEncoding.java:132)
at com.sun.pdfview.font.PDFFontEncoding.getGlyphs(PDFFontEncoding.java:98)
at com.sun.pdfview.font.PDFFont.getGlyphs(PDFFont.java:273)
at com.sun.pdfview.PDFTextFormat.doText(PDFTextFormat.java:283)
at com.sun.pdfview.PDFParser.iterate(PDFParser.java:742)
at com.sun.pdfview.BaseWatchable.run(BaseWatchable.java:88)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Regards,
Haythem

Comment: Which library are you using??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at these free pdf renderer ...

Some links ...

1. http://www.icepdf.org/ (now at http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEpdf/overview.jsf - Apache 2 Open Source)
2. http://www.jpedal.org/support_siEclipse.php (now at https://www.idrsolutions.com/jpedal/ - commercial)
3. https://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer (still available https://github.com/yarick123/pdf-renderer - LGPL-2.1)

**UPDATE**

As per http://www.icepdf.org/ ,

> ICEpdf is an open source Java PDF
>   engine that can render, convert, or
>   extract PDF content within any Java
>   application or on a Web server.

For basic functionality you have to include `icepdf-core.jar` and `icepdf-viewer.jar` in your class path. Depending upon the requirement you can also add the SVG support.

Taken from iceface sample folder:

```
import org.icepdf.ri.common.SwingController;
import org.icepdf.ri.common.SwingViewBuilder;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * The <code>ViewerComponentExample</code> class is an example of how to use
 * <code>SwingController</code> and <code>SwingViewBuilder</code>
 * to build a PDF viewer component.  A file specified at the command line is
 * opened in a JFrame which contains the viewer component.
 *
 * @since 2.0
 */
public class ViewerComponentExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Get a file from the command line to open
        String filePath = args[0];

        // build a component controller
        SwingController controller = new SwingController();

        SwingViewBuilder factory = new SwingViewBuilder(controller);

        JPanel viewerComponentPanel = factory.buildViewerPanel();

        // add interactive mouse link annotation support via callback
        controller.getDocumentViewController().setAnnotationCallback(
                new org.icepdf.ri.common.MyAnnotationCallback(
                        controller.getDocumentViewController()));

        JFrame applicationFrame = new JFrame();
        applicationFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        applicationFrame.getContentPane().add(viewerComponentPanel);

        // Now that the GUI is all in place, we can try openning a PDF
        controller.openDocument(filePath);

        // show the component
        applicationFrame.pack();
        applicationFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The above code helps you in displaying a PDF on a swing component. You can do the same in the SWT environment (have a look at `SwingViewBuilder` .. kind of hard, but will SWT look and feel ) or use `org.eclipse.swt.awt.SWT_AWT` (kind of easy... but will have swing + swt look and feel)... though both approach will solve your purpose. Also check the applicable licenses in the license folder.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yes I saw them but I cann't found a way to open existing PDF files and to show them on a view.

Comment: @Favonius: I am using org.nightlabs.eclipse.ui.pdfviewer

Comment: @Haythem:  As per nightlab page, they are internally using https://pdf-renderer.dev.java.net/ for rendering. Is there any image in the PDF file which is giving problem? The sun pdf-renderer is known to have problem with embedded tiff files. Have a look at this javalobby post http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t104502.html

Comment: @Haythem: Also from the https://pdf-renderer.dev.java.net/ this was the only known release. I will suggest having a look at http://www.jpedal.org/support_siEclipse.php the reader source  is also available on their page.

Comment: @Favoonius: I should use an opensource project like iText. Do you have an example how to show an existing pdf document on a view with iText or an opensource?

Comment: @Haythem: iText is a library to create, read or manipulate documents in the PDF format. You cannot use it for displaying/rendering pdf files. Although you can use icepdf. Check my updated answer.

Comment: For any future comers - you can get the JARs directly off their old Google code project [here](https://code.google.com/p/tpt/source/browse/trunk/modules/tpt-core/lib/icepdf/?r=19).

Comment: the point is, their font renderer engine is based on a license

Answer (score 4):

Here is another free, small and powerful PDF Viewer based on Eclipse SWT and jPod Renderer — [JPview](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpview/). It has strong rendering and low memory usage.