# view pdf in java swing using itext?

Tags: java, swing, itext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java PDF Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437910/java-pdf-viewer)

I'm beginner at java and itext. And I'm trying to read Pdf file as image in my own application...

As my understanding, in itext "reading a PDF a file" starts to create Document and read page by page PDF by PdfReader class and then writes read pages to Document by PdfWriter. Finally the Pdf has saved to Document. After that I can't import or show the Document to Java Swing Component?! Please tell me how.

Thanks for any replies and suggestions.

Comment: only for showing a pdf why you are trying to do that in java. for showing a pdf a normal pdf viewer is good enough.

Comment: Debobroto Das. I'm a student and i want to know and i want make my own. Everybody knows there so many of PDF Viewer!!!

Comment: *"want make my own"*  Don't try to reinvent that (very big) wheel.  Consider the number of lines of code of it took to make the Jars of iText.  Do you think that is a 'summer project'?

Comment: IText is **not** for viewing pdfs but for manipulating them. If you want a freely available viewer, you may want to look at jpedal.

Comment: Ok thanx buddies, 1st every programmer is reinventer, 2nd this is not summer project. thanks **mkl** I'll try jpedal

Answer (score 1):

iText is not a PDF renderer, it won't be of any use for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: There must have someway of solving this, I'll show if I've done