# Separating PDF pages in Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to separate one large PDF into several smaller PDFs of varying lengths. At first I tried reading the original PDF with a `FileInputStream` and finding the signature hex strings to split it into smaller files with a `FileOutputStream` (as I have done with JPGs). However, I can't seem to find what hex string designates different pages in the original.

I've been looking through the iText API for the `PdfWriter` and `PdfReader` classes but I'm not exactly sure how to write data from the original to the smaller PDF, let alone how to create a PDF file in the first place.

Which of these approaches makes more sense? Or is there a much simpler, more ideal way?

Comment: There is no such *page separation spot* in PDFs. PDF files consist of objects which can reference each other via a cross reference table.  Thus, the objects used for a given single page may be spread over the whole file. Furthermore, some of these objects may be used on multiple pages. E.g. embedded fonts or repeating header/footer parts.

Comment: Perhaps this. [iText in Action: Extracting Page Content](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=277)

Comment: @SriHarsha that is code for text extraction from pdfs.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in my comment to your question, there are no *signature hex strings to split* the source PDF at. PDF files consist of objects which can reference each other via a cross reference table. Thus, the objects used for a given single page may be spread over the whole file. Furthermore, some of these objects may be used on multiple pages. E.g. embedded fonts or repeating header/footer parts.

An API understanding the PDF format can create collections of partial documents from a multi-page source PDF, though.

In case of iText have a look at the [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/) example [Burst.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=129). The central code is this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SOURCE);
// We'll create as many new PDFs as there are pages
Document document;
PdfCopy copy;
// loop over all the pages in the original PDF
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
for (int i = 0; i < n; ) {
    document = new Document();
    copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(String.format(RESULT, ++i)));
    document.open();
    copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, i));
    document.close();
}
reader.close();
```

While this sample creates one result PDF for each single page, the source obviously indicates how to create result PDFs containing page ranges of the original.

Answer (score 1):

Well if your goal is to split a pdf file's pages here is where you should go about it : [click here](http://www.splitpdf.com/)
or just use acrobat (huge app)

but if you still want to use java, I think this will be useful to you (in creating pdf files from text): [click here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-javapdf/)
although I never used these libraries but they seem fine ..

and I think this topic will help you find your pdf reader : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437910/java-pdf-viewer)

I hope I could help even a little

Comment: the website's program isn't as helpful to me since I want the program to detect the different separation spots automatically (it's to shave time off of scanning hundreds of long files every day; currently, I just scan shorter PDF's individually). I think I can implement the auto-detection on my own.

The second link helps a lot with handling PDFs, though. I'm not sure how I didn't run across that page after all my searching. Thanks!

Comment: I never used the website really, just the acrobat ,, you're welcome :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are open to the idea of using a ready-made program, I have used this one to great effect:

[PDFTK](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)

It can split, combine, and rotate pages, and even has some built-in logic for specifying the order of the pages when re-combining (and can do it from multiple PDF files).

Comment: PdfTk is iText compiled with the GNU Compiler for Java. You might as well use the real thing. Read http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf to find out how it's done.