# How to open PDF file after being generated from a method

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need your help in opening the generated PDF file automatically after it is being written from a bean. I used `iText` libraries to write a PDF file and in the below method, I am able to generate the PDF, but I do not know how to open it on the fly for the users.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {

     Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);

     document.open();

    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(
        "c://windows/fonts/arialuni.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font font = new Font(bf, 25);
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    PdfPCell  cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Good Morning", font));
    cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    cell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
    table.addCell(cell);
    document.add(table);

    document.close();      

 }
```

I want the PDF file to be shown to the user after it is being written to allow him to print the file, so how can I do this?

Comment: Desktop.getDesktop().open(yourfile) ?

Comment: @chuchichaeschtli No I don't want it to be saved first of all, I need only to open it once it is generated without saving it

Comment: @chuchichaeschtli Please refer to the updated post. Also, is there a way to show the dialog box for Saving or opening the PDF file?

Comment: So you have an application installed on the user's computer (after all you use the `main` method) and want to show a PDF without saving it, i.e. one which exists only in memory. AFAIK that is not possible using standard PDF viewers existing on the user's computer. You could try a java PDF viewer component instead, e.g. jPedal.

Comment: @mkl Thanks mkl for the explanation now I got the point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just open the `pdf` file in the default pdf viewer installed in on the user's machine.

Use this.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("path/to/pdf"));
```

The file will be opened in the application whichever is installed on the target machine. (Adobe Reader, Nitro PDF, etc.)

Once the file is opened in the default viewer, the user will be able to print it by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: The above line will open the PDF file, if it is saved on the Desktop. My requirement is a little bit different, once I write the PDF and reaches the document.close();  I need to to open the PDF file automatically without Saving it in the user machine similar to generating it on the fly and showing it to the user

Comment: Or is there a way to show the dialog box for Saving or opening the PDF file?

Comment: What you need is PDF renderer OR PDF viewer. This has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4437985/4338417).

Comment: Actually I am using Primefaces and I am new to it and this is my first time that I am writing a PDF file and I do not know how to display it on the browser.