# Should I download a library to import com.sun.pdfview.*?

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf

When i decided to import com.sun.pdfview.* to my program it marked an error where it specified that I should create a package for it but when I did it still gave me an error, should I download a library to be able to use it? Which one?

ps.Im using eclipse as my IDE

Comment: Why are you using a library last updated in 2009?  You can get it from [Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.swinglabs/pdf-renderer/1.0.5) but I'd strongly encourage you to use something from this decade.

Comment: Thank you so much, can you recommend me a similar but newer library ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  The link to the company associated with that library doesn't work any more.  From [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437910/java-pdf-viewer) it looks like there are alternative PDF viewers.

Comment: I am trying to do my own pdf viewer for a project and what i wanted to do was include a pagepanel inside my frame so that the user wouldnt be able to save the pdf, it already worked